# Obtener consulta de 3 tablas relacionadas una de ellas con slug

Tags: sql, laravel

Buenas tardes estoy sacando datos relacionados pero me de doy cuenta que en una de las tablas tenia que guardar un campo que no hago, a ver si es posible hacer lo que quiero sin necesidad de modificar todo:

**Tengo una tabla productos**

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Producto 1 | producto-1 |
| 2 | Producto 2 | producto-2 |

**Otra tabla llamada combinations, donde guardo las variaciones de un producto**

| id | product_id | combination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | 1 | combinación-10-cajas |
| 133 | 1 | combinación-50-cajas |

**Otra tabla llamada terminos**

| id | termino | combination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 cajas | 10-cajas |
| 2 | 50 cajas | 50-cajas |

**Modelo `combinations`:**

```
protected $table = 'combinations';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'id');
    }
```

**Query para ver la información del producto que entro**

```
$producto = Product::join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
                            ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nombreCategoria', 'categories.id AS idCategory')
                            ->where('products.
```

visiblePara', 3)->where('products.slug', $titulo)->first();

**Luego en la vista de producto**

Saco las posibles variaciones del producto:

```
@foreach ($producto->combinations as $item)
    @php $str = substr($item->combination, 13); @endphp
    @php $namePro = ucfirst($str); @endphp
      <option value="{{ $item->id }}"> {{str_replace("-"," ",$namePro)}}</option>  
@endforeach
```

Lo que hago es quitarle los guiones y que empiece a leer desde el caracter número 13. Pero a pesar que funciona necesito que en lugar de sacar la columna de `combinations` llamada `combination` haga una relación con la tabla `terminos` y me saque el nombre que está en la columna `termino`.

Esto es posible?? estoy atascado y no se como hacer una query que quite esos primeros 13 caracteres.

Comment: Hola @BetaM realmente no hay relación, por que no guardo la id del termino, pero si hay una posible relación, con por ejemplo `combinación-10-cajas` de combinations con `10-cajas` de terminos. Solo puedo mostrarte la query que pongo al entrar en el producto

Comment: Por eso comentaba si se le puede eliminar esos primeros 13 caracteres antes de consultar

Comment: Si siempre, son permutas que añaden la palabra `combinación-` en todas ellas @BetaM

Comment: Si, pero las permutas se construyen solas, se que es como repetir valores, pero en este caso es necesario

Comment: Esperemos a que alguien mas publique alguna respuesta, en mi caso siento que el problema viene de una no adecuada relación entre las entidades involucradas, pero como menciono esperemos a que otra persona aporte

Comment: Entiendo, y si a la tabla terminos le añado un campo que cuando add/edit un termino le ponga combinacion y su slug? siempre serán iguales, así seria posible hacer una relación @BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que el problema inicial no tiene que ver en si con *Laravel* sino con la relación existente entre tus 3 tablas y por ende la búsqueda de valores relacionados entre ellas.

Comentarios:

1. De la tabla *combinations* estás buscando filtrar y quedarte solo con parte del valor del string en la columna *combination*, aquí surge mi primera duda:

   - ¿si buscas comparar solo con parte del texto entonces para qué almacenas mas de lo necesario?

     - Es decir almacena en dicha columna también solo el texto: *10-cajas*
   - Ahora considera que si es el caso y en ambas estuvieras almacenando el mismo valor *Xnumero_cajas* entonces estas duplicando información, lo cual no tiene mucho sentido
2. Otro aspecto importante a mencionar es que según la información que expones parece ser que: *muchos productos pueden tener muchas combinations y muchas combinations pueden pertenecer a muchos productos*

   - Dado lo anterior, entonces puedo considerar que la relación que debe existir es de *muchos a muchos* donde participen:

- Productos
- Combinations (*la tabla intermedia*)
- Terminos

Así pues entonces en la tabla combinations puedes almacenar las *pk* de cada extremo de esta forma:

Combinations:

```
fk_producto | fk_termino |
     1            1
     1            2
     2            2
     2            1
```

Productos:

```
pk |    name   |   slug

1    producto 1 producto-1
2    producto 2 producto-2
```

Terminos:

```
pk |    termino   |   slug

1      50 cajas     50-cajas
2      10 cajas     10-cajas
```

De tal manera que si quieres el slug de termino, el nombre del producto y el slug del producto entonces puedes plantear una query similar a esta:

```
SELECT productos.name,
       productos.slug,
       terminos.slug
FROM productos 
INNER JOIN combinations ON productos.id = combinations.fk_producto
INNER JOIN terminos ON terminos.id = combinations.fk_combination;
```

De esta manera evitas:

- Registros (parcialmente) duplicados
- Tener que plantear con el lenguaje de proogramación técnicas que ayuden a *cortar* cada *string*
- Tener que replantear el código si en algún momento la descripción de cada slug cambia e incluso tiene variaciones de un registro a otro